# how to create perl aliases? typeglobs?

Tags: perl, alias, perl-module

Suppose I'm manipulating a hash that's in another package, and I want to create an alias to that variable?  What's a clean way to do that?  This sample code shows what I want to do, but it, and a dozen variations of it malfunction.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;  # I want it to work with strict.

my $p = Person->new("Joe");
my $name;
*name = \*$p->{"name"};     # Latest broken attempt

printf("'%s' should eq '%s' because they both point to the same place.\n",
       $name, $p->{"name"});

$name = "Sam";

printf("'%s' should eq '%s' because they both point to the same place.\n",
       $name, $p->{"name"});
exit 0;


package Person;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my $this = {};
    bless $this, $class;

    $this->{"name"} = shift;

    return $this;
}
```

The functionality I want is to be able to manipulate `$p->{"name"}` dozens of times without having to type `$p->{"name"}` repeatedly.  The real data structure is far more complex with a lot of nested hashes.

It's probably something easy.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a copy:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $p = { name => "Joe" };
my $name = $p->{name};
print "'$name' is '$p->{name}'\n";
```

This is what I'd use if I don't need to assign to `$name`.

If you want to be able to write through `$name`, the easiest way is to make it a reference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $p = { name => "Joe" };
my $name = \$p->{name};
print "'$$name' is '$p->{name}'\n";
$$name = "Jill";
print "'$$name' is '$p->{name}'\n";
```

If you really want an alias, the easiest way is to abuse a `for` loop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $p = { name => "Joe" };
for my $name ($p->{name}) {
    print "'$name' is '$p->{name}'\n";
    $name = "Jill";
    print "'$name' is '$p->{name}'\n";
}
```

If your perl is new enough (5.22+), you can also do aliasing through references:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'refaliasing';
my $p = { name => "Joe" };
\my $name = \$p->{name};
print "'$name' is '$p->{name}'\n";
$name = "Jill";
print "'$name' is '$p->{name}'\n";
```

Finally, you can do aliasing to package variables by assigning to typeglobs, but that's not something I'd actually use here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $p = { name => "Joe" };
*name = \$p->{name};  # sets *name{SCALAR} to point to $p->{name}
our $name;            # declares $name so we can use it to refer to $main::name
print "'$name' is '$p->{name}'\n";
$name = "Jill";
print "'$name' is '$p->{name}'\n";
```

Comment: The third way to do aliasing is using Data::Alias.

Comment: Is it really any different than refaliasing?

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, it does some pretty gruesome stuff with perl internals. See https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Alias#IMPLEMENTATION.

Comment: If you want to change the language, you either need to actually change the parser (refaliasing) or hook into it (Data::Alias). It's not really any different.